# How to create KMZ file on C#

Tags: c#, kmz

How can I create .kmz ( google earth file format ) ? I will use the C#. There is information about .KML everywhere. I did not find anywhere. I can use excel.

thank you for your help. 
best wishes.

Comment: So [the documentation](https://developers.google.com/kml/documentation/kmzarchives) of the file format, as supplied by Google, wasn't of any help?

Comment: Read [ask] and [mcve].  Delete or edit your post accordingly.

Comment: There even seem to be [NuGet packages](https://www.nuget.org/packages/ThinkGeo.MapSuite.Layers.Kml/10.5.0) that deal with Keyhole Markup Language.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to the [Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Keyhole_Markup_Language), KMZ files are simple Xml files in a ZIP container.

You should be able to use the regular [`XmlWriter`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.xml.xmlwriter) included in .NET's base class library to write the KML document, then wrap it in a ZIP file either with .NET's no-board methods or with a 3rd party library.

A reference for the Xml-based KML format is linked to in the Wikipedia article.